# Images not showing properly in email when site is password protected

Tags: magento-1.9, security, .htaccess

My Magento development website is password protected through .htaccess and .htpasswd. I have a *share via email* feature in my website. On click of product share an email is sent with image of product.

Email is sent no issues in this but issue is images are not shown in the email. If i remove password protect rule from .htaccess file and share the product, image is seen properly in the email with out an issue.

I want to display image in the email when my site having password protect rule in the .htaccess

Comment: Exclude the media directory from htpasswd
follow 
https://perishablepress.com/enable-file-or-directory-access-to-your-htaccess-password-protected-site/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had done by adding following code in the .htaccess file present in media/

```
Satisfy Any
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
```

Answer (score 4):

Thats the correct behavior. Most of the Mail Clients can't or do not want interpret the password protection, because it can be used for phishing attacks. Web Mail-Clients like google, even didn't show the original Image path in the Mail. They try to catch the Image from the server and display it by it own.

What you can do is to modify the .htaccess and allow specific IPs.

> Allow from 127.0.0.1

You can try to add your IP or die IP of the recipient and if this didn't help, you can try to add the IP from the Mail-Client Server.

Another solution would be to allow the /media/ directory.